# Nodejs can I make a GET request to my own application?

Tags: node.js, http, routes, request, cron

I have a route in my app that I've defined with tasks to be run in the style of a few cron jobs. I know that this can be triggered by a GET request from an external devise when necessary (and that's ideal). (FYI: I will be adding validations for security purposes to this route.)

```
router.get('/cron', function(req) {
  /**
   *
   * Do cron things...
   */
  task();
});
```

What I'm wondering is if I'd also be able to trigger this via a GET request from my own system when necessary?

What would be really helpful is to reuse the same route above with an npm module like [node-crontab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-crontab) and simply make a request to the route every few hours.

```
var doEveryThirtyMinutes = crontab.scheduleJob("*/30 * * * *", function(){
  /**
   * Make GET request to '/cron' controller.
   * Live a happy life. 
   */
});
```

I can't find any information on how to make that request (to my same system), even in the [npm request module](https://github.com/request/request) documentation. Is there a reason not to do this? Am I missing something? Is this a bad practice?

The reason this setup would be incredibly beneficial is that I connect to my database via an extension of the req object and don't want to implement a new connection module. Also, I already have a logging procedure implemented for successful/ unsuccessful route executions, so I would be able to reuse that as well.

Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just put the task in its own js file and just run it directly instead of exposing it to the web, or even calling it from either the web or the cron task?

Comment: Hi @MiltoxBeyond, yes the last paragraph I wrote contains two reasons why. I use a single connection database configuration that extends the req  object in my application and I not want to implement a new connection module that I would need to instantiate in my cron jobs sans the req object. Also, I already have a pretty solid logging on fail/ success procedure that I would be able to reuse among a lot of other things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a get request to your own application. You would make this request like any other request, just use your application's host and port.

If you want to grab the hostname from your os, you can do this with require('os').hostname
https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_hostname

The reason you wouldn't do this is you are already in your application, so you shouldn't need to communicate via it's network interface.